# libvlc_new emits SIGABRT signal

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, sigabrt, libvlc

I'm trying to use libvlc to display a video inside a Qt 5.0.2 x64 application.

The way to use this library begins by starting to initialize a instance of `libvlc_instance_t` using `libvlc_new` method like this:

```
libvlc_instance_t *instance = libvlc_new(0,NULL);
```

I do not know why but this causes a `SIGABRT` signal terminating the application, afterwards I also get this debug message:

> QMetaType::registerType: Binary compatibility break -- Size mismatch
>   for type 'QPaintBufferCacheEntry' [1024]. Previously registered size
>   16, now registering size 0.

One thing I've noticed is that the application takes a few seconds to start and while she does I can see it crawling through VLC plugins folder. When finished it emits a `SIGABRT` signal and ends.

Does anyone knows why `libvlc_new` is emitting a `SIGABRT`?

If it helps I load the library into the application as a system package with `pkg-config`:

**app.pro**

```
unix: CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
unix: PKGCONFIG += libvlc
```

I'm using `libvlc` and `VLC 2.1.4 Rincewind` (from repositories) running under Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (x64) `3.13.0-36-generic` with multi arch enabled for `i386`

**Edit:** Forgot to mention that the application is 64 bits.

**ANSWER:** 6 Nov 2014

The problem was VLC plugin cache. It needed to be refreshed/updated.

```
sudo /usr/lib/vlc/vlc-cache-gen -f /usr/lib/vlc/plugins
```

As a precaution you might want to reinstall `VLC` and `libvlc` before doing so.